# Android: Listview shows wrong images while scrolling

Tags: android

i am downloading images from internet using universal image loader. Some pictures are being set as avatars so i'm rounding them and others are being stretched. the problem is the listview shows wrong image when scrolling and after a while it shows the correct image. i've searched stackoverflow for similar problem but i cant get it to work rightly.

i'm using custom adapter and the getview code and the code for rounding and streching image are as follows:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatsnew_listitem, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.playButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_playVideo);
        holder.mediaThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_mediaImage);
        holder.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_avatar);
        holder.artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_artistName);
        holder.timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_timestamp);
        holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    pos = position;
    Item item = items.get(position);

    if(item.getArtistName() != "")
    {
        // set thumbnail
        String thumbnailURL = "";
        holder.mediaThumbnail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(item.getUpdateType() == Config.UPDATE_TYPE_1)
        { 
            holder.playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thumbnailURL = item.getPictureUri();

            if(thumbnailURL != null) 
            {

                ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(thumbnailURL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                        setImage(loadedImage, imageView, Config.MEDIA);
                        mediaImages[position] = true;
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
            }

            holder.status.setText(item.getMessage());
        } 
        else if(item.getUpdateType() == Config.UPDATE_TYPE_2) 
        {
            //play button
            holder.playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //set media image
            thumbnailURL = item.getVideoThumbnailUri();
            if(thumbnailURL != null)
            {
                ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(thumbnailURL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) 
                    {
                        setImage(loadedImage, imageView, Config.MEDIA);
                        mediaImages[position] = true;
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }

            //set youtube status
            holder.status.setText(item.getTitle());
            holder.playButton.bringToFront();
            holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(item.getVideoId()!= null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(Config.YOUTUBE_URI + item.getVideoId() ));
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //set avatar

        String avatarURL = item.getAvatarImageUri();
        holder.avatar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(avatarURL != null)// && avatarImages[position] == false)
        {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(avatarURL, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    setImage(loadedImage, imageView, Config.AVATAR);
                    avatarImages[position] = true;
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
        }

        //set artist name
        holder.artistName.setText(item.getArtistName());

        //set timestamp
        if(timerList[position] == false)
        {
            updateTime(holder.timestamp, item);
        }
    }


    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}

//@Override
public void setImage(final Bitmap bitmap, final ImageView imageView, final String imagetype) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Bitmap croppedBmp = null;
            int imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            int imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

            if(imagetype == Config.MEDIA) 
            {            
                if(imageHeight <imageWidth) {
                    croppedBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, dp, dp, true);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);
                }
            } 
            else if(imagetype == Config.AVATAR) 
            {

                int radius;
                if(imageWidth >  imageHeight) 
                {
                    croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageHeight, imageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                    radius = imageHeight/2;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageWidth, imageWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                    radius = imageWidth/2;
                } 

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBmp);      
                final int color = 0xff424242;
                final Paint paint = new Paint();
                final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                paint.setColor(color);
                canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, imageView, listener)
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

use this method

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

and get the type as follows in getView()

```
int type = getItemViewType(position);
```

I solved my issue following the example

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the views outside the if else condition

```
if(view == null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatsnew_listitem, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

 holder.playButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_playVideo);
        holder.mediaThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_mediaImage);
        holder.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_avatar);
        holder.artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_artistName);
        holder.timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_timestamp);
        holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
```

Comment: Loading imageviews is a timetaking task. Are you handling the download in an asynctask and onpostexecute of that you are setting adapter to listview?

Comment: i'm using universal image loader to download images from net. i overrode the function onLoadingCompleted and set the bitmap to the imageview there

Answer (score 0):

use override mthod of ImageLoader

```
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUri, (ImageView) view);

    }
```

and in displayOptions use a stub image that will be displayed until the image loads from URL.

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.com_facebook_profile_default_icon).build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).build();
```

Comment: tried it .. it doesn't show any stub images .. but the imageview get shuffled..after a while it shows the correct image

Comment: do you use that override method?

Comment: i selected one from my drawable folder but it doesn't seem to show any stub image .. seems like the shuffling of images happening due to listview scrolling

Answer (score 0):

In each moment ListView display several elements (those who "fits" to the display), and instead of creating a new, during flicking, new elements replaced the old one in the list

Try this:

```
public class Info {
    private ImageView mediaThumbnail;
    private ImageView avatar; 
        ...

    public ImageView getMediaThumbnail() {
        return mediaThumbnail;
    }

    public void setMediaThumbnail(ImageView mediaThumbnail) {
        this.mediaThumbnail = mediaThumbnail;
    }
        ...
}
```

In adapter add to ViewHolder field `Info info` and write next code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    row = convertView;
    Info info = getItem(position);

    if (null == row)
        setupRow(parent, info);
    else
        getRow(info);
    ...
}

private void setupRow(ViewGroup parent, Info info) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.playButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_playVideo);
    holder.mediaThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_mediaImage);
    holder.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_avatar);
    holder.artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_artistName);
    holder.timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_timestamp);
    holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
    view.setTag(holder);
}

private void getRow(DownloadInfo info) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        holder.info.setMediaThumbnail(null);
        ...
        holder.info = info;

        holder.info.setMediaThumbnail(holder.mediaThumbnail);
        ...
    }
```